# Virtual Terminal WITHOUT merchant account?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, banking, money-transfer, debit-card

Is there any such thing as access to the credit/debit/prepaid cards (issued worldwide) online charging Virtual Terminal without having to be approved for merchant account? So without owning it. I recently started my 3D HOME modelling services, targeting clients and potential clients who want to either buy new apartment/house or renovate existing one. Due to good online marketing, I am getting new clients every day but the problem is that I don't have company (it is my own business - only me and no ''company'' at all) documents. Every merchant account provider, being able to offer me virtual terminal, want from me those documents. Since I am not interested about card processing gateway, the Virtual Terminal is a must for me. How and where could I get access to it?

Comment: The most basic business model is you as a sole proprietorship.  Barbers and stylists often rent space in a shop, and have the services of providers like Paypal, Square or Intuit to bill their clients; the SHOP doesn't have to get a merchant account.  So barber Joe Jones swipes your card (or enters it into the virtual terminal on his phone) and your c/c statement shows a $15 charge from Joe Jones.  Seems you're overcomplicating this.  You don't need a business entity (corporation, LLC) to get a virtual terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to setup a company (even if it's just a sole proprietorship, in the US) to be able to apply for a true merchant account.  And thus have a terminal; either real or virtual in your home or business.

However, many services such as paypal allow you to accept credit cards (both online and with a card reader) and when the customer is billed it appears as paypal + your account name.  So you essentially have the benefits of a merchant account, without having to set one up.